# Best way to mix static html and backbone data in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: backbone.js

At the moment I am forced to use character escaping to mix my static html with my model data but there has to be a better way.

I am currently using .aspx views and this is how ugly some of my views look.

```
$('ul#spaceImage', this.el).append("<li id=\"" + item.get("HoverId") + "\" class=\"hover\" style=\"left:" + x + "px;top:" + y + "px\"><span class=\"newlyAdded\"></span>" + item.get("MaterialGroupName") + "<a></a></li>");
```

Is there a way to display this without character escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are having issues using underscore templates because they share asp.net syntax?  If so you can use [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and move your template code to a to a script block in your asp markup.

Markup:

```
<script type="text/html" id="list-item-template">
  <li id="{{HoverId}}" class="{{hover}}" style="left:<%=x%>px;top:<%=y%>px">
    <span class="newlyAdded"></span>
    <a><{{MaterialGroupName}}></a>
  </li>
</script>
```

Backbone View:

```
render: function() {
  var template = Handlebars.compile($("#list-item-template").html());
  $(this.el).html(template({this.model.toJSON()}));
  return this;
}
```